# How Facebook do to expand the text of a large post? Add a "... More" and expand it

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to do something like Facebook does when you post a large text that shows you something like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam
>   commodo venenatis nisl id convallis.
>   Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
>   dis parturient montes, nascetur
>   ridiculus mus. Pellentesque habitant
>   morbi tristique senectus et netus et
>   malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
>   Duis nec odio a libero consequat
>   pretium **... More**

So I can output all the text and, with jQuery, select a maximum of words, add the ... plus "More" and when I click it expand all the text remaining? All this without AJAX.

I will combine this with PHP for a multilingual site and I need to be able to change easily the word "More" for language support.

Sorry my English is not my main language and explain this is hard to me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many plugins out there to do this, [the jQuery Expander plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/) is one of the most popular. [You can try out a demo here](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html).

Or, there are lighter versions like [truncate](http://theodin.co.uk/blog/development/truncatable-jquery-plugin.html), you can [try it here](http://theodin.co.uk/tools/tutorials/jqueryTutorial/plugins/truncatable/),

Comment: Thank you, there is a trick valid for me in this Expander plugin that allows you to put the link to the text and let you expand it from that link. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the version, that operates on lines of text rather than letters or words? I need to expand/collapse lines, showing text like "show X more..." in collapsed state. It's about showing a long list of goods in the news.